# Calling protected __construct from closure... works in 5.4.14, not in 5.3?

Tags: php

I have the following class defined (snippet presented here)...

```
class JEH_User
{
    // <snip>

    protected function __construct(&$propertyHash)
    {
        $this->usrVals = $propertyHash;
        // <snip>
    }

    // <snip>

    static public function FindAll()
    {
        $retAry = Array();
        $db = JEH_DBase::GetDBase();

        $db->LockTables( Array( '__JEH_USER' => JEH_DBase::LOCK4READ) );
        $db->Execute(
                "SELECT * from __JEH_USER;",
                Array(),
                function ($r) use (&$retAry) {
                    $retAry[] = new JEH_User($r);
                    return TRUE;
                } );
        $db->UnlockAllTables();

        return $retAry;
    }   

    // <snip>
}
```

My problem is this... originally (and I confess without really thinking about why it should or shouldn't work) in the function `FindAll()` I pass a closure back to by DB `Execute()` function. All this function does is do some sanity checking and then execute the SQL, then for each row returned calls the closure/callback with that row.

The problem is that in PHP 5.4(.14) this works. The closure seems to bind to the class context it's being created in and so can call the `protected __construct()` constructor. In 5.3(.23), that my provider runs, this is not the case and it complains that

```
Fatal error: Call to protected JEH_User::__construct() from invalid context in ... <snip>
```

So, my question is, can I overcome this in PHP 5.3 without too many mods to my code base? I've had a little google to try and find out the differences between .3 and .4 in this case. Ive seen the `Closure::bind()` function but this is 5.4...

Also, the manual says

```
5.4.0   $this can be used in anonymous functions.
5.3.0   Anonymous functions become available.
```

Oh dear! Does anyone know any "quick" fixes or is this a re-write for PHP 5.3 job?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The quickest one would be to make constructor public.

Comment: lol, actually yes very good point. if there isn't an easy work around I might as well!

Answer (score 2):

You can take some code from a famous pattern and have a static method that returns an instance of the class.

```
class JEH_User 
{
// <snip>

protected function __construct(&$propertyHash)
{
    $this->usrVals = $propertyHash;
    // <snip>
}

public static function getInstance() {
      return new JEH_User();
}
```

and in your calling code use

```
 $instance = JEH_User::getInstance();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. This seems unfortunately to be the same as just making the constructor public because I'm not trying to implement a singleton or anything like that. Thanks for taking the time though :)